# Java threads: timers, interruption

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's suppose I have a method `task()`to be executed in separate thread. A thread running this method is able to be correctly stopped (i.e. it correctly handles `InterruptedException` and checks `isInterrupted` flag periodically).

I want to run  this method with timeout. To be more precise, once timeout is over I just want to tell this separate thread that it's time to finish (by setting `isInterrupted` flag) and wait until the thread checks it and terminates safely.

I don't want to roughly stop it using `Thread.stop()` as it is unsafe, and I don't want proceed code execution in main thread until the `task()` thread is terminated.

What comes to my mind is something like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> task());
thread.start();
thread.join(timeout);
thread.interrupt();
thread.join();
// proceed main thread execution
```

So my questions are:

1. Is it a correct solution?
2. Isn't it a pretty common scenario, and if so, is there something in java `java.util.concurrent` to implement it? I would like to use something like `java.util.concurrent.Future` to be able to get return value from `task()`, what I can't with the solution above.

Comment: `I would like to use something like java.util.concurrent.Future to be able to get return value from task()`  Calling `get()` with a timeout doesn't work?

Comment: Calling `get()` with a timeout either returns a result or throws `TimeoutException`. What should I do in the second case? I can invoke `Future.cancel(true)` in order to interrupt thread, but I still need the result, and any next call of `get()` will just throw `CancellationException`

Comment: Yeah that's weird.  You need to get a result even though you've cancelled the thread early?  I'd guess you need to pass the result (or maybe a stream of intermediate results) some other way, like perhaps in a shared concurrent queue.